# Draw texture on finger movement in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I want to create an app in Cocos2d/Cocos2dx in which i have an image which is not visible but when i move my finger on device it start drawing. Only that part of image draws where i move my finger.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you mean like revealing a picture? or would the part of the image move along with the finger?

Comment: i don't want to reveal the image i want to draw the image. You can see makeup games for reference. here's one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.libiitech.weddingsalon

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of drawing an image.

The first way would be like a brush. You would use RenderTexture and draw/visit a brush sprite to draw it into this texture. If you just need to draw with solid colors (can have opacity) you could also use the primitive draw commands (drawCircle, drawPoly, drawSegment). You will need a high rate of touch tracking and will likely want to draw segments or bezier curves between touch movements to catch fast movements.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/using-rendertexture-to-render-one-sprite-multiple-times/16332/3

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/freehand-drawing-app-with-cocos2d-x-v3-3-using-rendertexture/17567/9

Searching on how other drawing games work would be useful.

The second way I can envision it is similar to revealing except using an inverse mask. So you would draw a set image, but reveal that image by drawing. 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/4428/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-2-0

There are more elaborate ways to handle the drawing into the RenderTexture in order to have the brush design tile correctly and repeat based on a given size, but that'll involve making something closer to an image editing tool.